# Rails ActiveRecord add zero before 2 character records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We did a db migration from mysql to postgres, and one table in the new postgres db used an Integer type for a 3 character column originally, but it removed the leading zero for numbers like 031.

We have changed it to a string type columns and are looking for a way in the rails console to update any records that only have two characters by adding a leading zero.

Model: `Profile`

Column: `number`

```
Profile.update(???)
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

EDIT: Here's the final command that worked great:

```
Profile.where('length(number) < 3').each { |profile| profile.update(number: profile.number.rjust(3, "0")) }
```

Comment: Do you want to do it via the rails console or migration (and ActiveRecord) or is a PostGres solution acceptable?

Comment: Rails Console would be best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
"12".rjust(3, "0")
```

What this does is `rjust`, right justifies, by taking the width you want the string to be and a padding string to fill the gap with.

[Stdlib Doc for rjust](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-rjust)